# Arch linux can't login

Tags: arch-linux, devices, startup

My problem is that I can't login. If I try to loggin with correct username and password it doesn't do anything. I have error message on boot `failed to create static device Nodes in /dev` . This happened after `sudo pacman -Sy xterm` and restart of the system. My kernel version is `4.1.6-1-ARCH`
 This is not my image but by this I mean loggin session.[image]. [image][image]

Comment: “can't login” isn’t a problem report usable for experts.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi better?

Comment: Has your OS a ready-to-use emergency/recovery mode? Even if it hasn’t, playing with kernel boot parameters in the bootloader, one can say the kernel to run at the `s` (single user mode) runlevel, or even without a genuine init (`init=/bin/bash`). Then examine the root file system for damage.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi i have added two images.

Comment: It seems you have something really, really wrong with your shared libraries. What did you do prior to this happening?

Comment: I have installed xterm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Libncurses was recently updated from `/usr/lib32/libncursesw.so.5` to `/usr/lib32/libncursesw.so.6`. There would have been a matching bash update, but you don't have it.

In fact, I just found this in my own `pacman.log`:

```
[2015-09-19 23:45] [ALPM] upgraded ncurses (5.9-7 -> 6.0-3)
[2015-09-19 23:45] [ALPM] upgraded readline (6.3.008-1 -> 6.3.008-3)
[2015-09-19 23:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] /usr/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libncursesw.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2015-09-19 23:45] [ALPM] upgraded bash (4.3.042-1 -> 4.3.042-3)
```

This is why you should update everything or nothing.

You should get a LiveCD, mount the drive, and do the updates like this:

```
pacman --root=/path/to/mounted/root -Suy
```

Comment: I have fixed it :) but thanks :) .

Answer (score -1):

I had this exact same issue after doing a full system upgrade.

Installing the updates with pacman --root=/mnt -Syu as described by "ams" did not resolve the problem for me; instead I had to symlink the library, i.e.

```
cd /usr/lib
ln -s libncursesw.so.6 libncursesw.so.5
```

However, after doing this, I can't run gnome-terminal (I have this issue: [gnome-terminal stopped working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231152/gnome-terminal-stopped-working)). That's probably not related to the ncurses issue, though.

Comment: Linking the two together is unlikely to work properly because the two libraries have different binary interfaces.

Comment: If you need nurses 5, use the [AUR version](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ncurses5-compat-libs/)

Comment: Ignore what I previously wrote about xterm input being messed up. I had recompiled xterm ages ago with some... let's just say experimental modifications, left it in /usr/local/bin, and forgot about it. Upon moving that binary elsewhere, xterm is absolutely fine.

Comment: and do a `pacman -Syu` after that.