# gnome-terminal stopped working

Tags: arch-linux, gnome-terminal

My `gnome-terminal 3.16.2-1` stopped working after a system update. I am running `Linux arch 4.1.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug 17 08:52:28 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

When launching it I recieve

```
Error constructing proxy for     org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 8
```

Googling the problem told me to re-set the locale settings. For that I opened `/etc/locale.gen` and made sure that `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` was uncommented.

I then ran `sudo locale-gen` to generate the locales. To top things off I also ran `localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and rebooted.

When the problem first arose I did recieve an error message that had to do with the locale. After doing the previous steps those error messages disappeared, but `gnome-terminal` still does not work. The above error message remains.

Strange behaviour that I can otherwise observe:

My Nautilus file manager will not start from the desktop shortcut, but does start without problems from the console.

`gnome-terminal` **does launch** when run as root.

`locale` outputs:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

`localectl` outputs

```
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   VC Keymap: us
  X11 Layout: us,de
```

Comment: There was no ~/.profile so I created that file and put it in there. It is the only text in the file, is that right? Even after rebooting it does not work.

Comment: Okay apparently bash looks for existing files in /etc/profile and then ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile in that order until it finds an existing one. I had a ~/.bash_profile so I added the language setting to that as well as to /etc/profile but to no avail.

Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Appended outputs in my edit.

Comment: Sorry, this took me a while to get done. No, it does not work for another user either. Same behavior.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but have no idea how to solve it. I'll try to downgrade some stuff, to see if it works again.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be a known upstream bug, have a look here: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/46374

Comment: What desktop environment/window manager are you using? When I had the problem, the issue was that I hadn't sourced `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*` in my `.xinitrc`.

Comment: I am using `GNOME Shell 3.16.3`. My `~/.xinitrc` only contains `xset -b` and `exec gnome-session`. Are you suggesting I should add `source /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*` to it?

Answer (score 8):

**Solution**:

Run in the terminal (alt+ctrl+F1 if you have only `gnome-terminal` installed), but remember is not permanent so after reboot you will need to do it again:

```
dbus-update-activation-environment --all
```

Or to solve it permanently (assuming that you have missing script in your `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d` see explanation for more details) load in your `~/.xinitrc` proper scripts:

```
if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
  for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
    [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
  done
  unset f
fi
```

Make notice that this will work only if you will have proper script in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d`

**Explanation**:

In my case the problem was missing `DISPLAY` variable for D-Bus session services.
Due to that, I could not start `gnome-terminal` nor `nautilius`.

I am using `Arch Linux` with `Slim` and some customized `.xinitrc`. Due to that, I missed loading additional stuff from `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/`. In case of `Arch Linux` there is script called  `50-systemd-user.sh` which takes care of setting up a proper environment for a D-Bus session. In my case it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

systemctl --user import-environment DISPLAY XAUTHORITY

if which dbus-update-activation-environment >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    dbus-update-activation-environment DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
fi
```

My understanding is that the `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` variables are imported into the systemd manager environment block and also to `dbus-daemon --session` which use those variables when activating session services. 
Some applications (it also depends on how they are called) fail due to missing those variables during start.

Comment: Worked for me. I was getting error code 10 with gnome-terminal on a frash install of Arch Linux with gnome.

Comment: This did not work for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: using "systemctl --user import-environment DISPLAY XAUTHORITY" fixes my broken gnome-terminal that I like to run on Windows under Cygwin (using ssh forwarding and running gnome-terminal off my Debian box).    Running that command first fixes gnome-terminal and it appears again on the X server machine!

Answer (score 7):

I added the following line to `~/.profile` It sets DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable. It solved the problem for me.

```
eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax`
```

Answer (score 1):

Append the following line at the bottom of ~/.bashrc and a reboot works for me

```
dbus-update-activation-environment --all
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,after changing localectl, I  modified my `.vnc/xstartup` file by commenting out this line below:-

```
gnome-session --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug &
```

Here's how my .vnc/xstartup looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:Unity"
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

#gnome-session --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
```