# Make user systemd service persistent

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, tmux

I have this `~/.config/systemd/user/weechat.service` systemd service which worked fine but after system upgrade the process gets killed which it didn't do before. The process is killed immediately when disconnected from SSH session.

```
[Unit]
Description=Weechat IRC Client (in tmux)
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux -2 -u new-session -d -s irc /usr/bin/weechat
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux kill-session -t irc

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Status:

```
% systemctl --user status weechat.service
● weechat.service - Weechat IRC Client (in tmux)
   Loaded: loaded (/home/<user>/.config/systemd/user/weechat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2017-10-05 22:54:54 EEST; 18h ago
  Process: 504 ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux -2 -u new-session -d -s irc /usr/bin/weechat (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 504 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/weechat.service
           ├─506 /usr/bin/tmux -2 -u new-session -d -s irc /usr/bin/weechat
           └─507 /usr/bin/weechat
```

`/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
[Login]
KillUserProcesses=no
```

I've booted the system and also tried restarting `systemd-logind.service`.

Which config file / process / daemon is issuing the kill after logout?

Comment: When you analyse the main pid (504) in the example, is the parent process showing as 1?

Comment: @RamanSailopal PID 504 isn't running. Looking at pid 506 reports parent PID as 498. 498's parent PID is 1.

Answer (score 16):

You need to tell systemd to 'linger' your user:

```
# loginctl enable-linger <user>
```

This will cause your user services to be started on boot, and for logind to keep them around after you logout (e.g. close your ssh session).

Comment: To see whether lingering is enabled for your user, execute `loginctl show-user $(whoami) --property Linger`.