# How is a new Terminal (gnome-terminal) created?

Tags: terminal, gnome, gnome-terminal

Whenever I create a new terminal its PPID is set to the one as `gnome-terminal-server` even when it's created using `bash`:

```
 3340 22404 22404 22404 ?           -1 Ssl   1000   1:16  \_ /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
22404 23096 23096 23096 pts/1    23096 Ss+   1000   0:00      \_ bash
22404 23563 23563 23563 pts/0    23613 Ss    1000   0:00      \_ bash
23563 23613 23613 23563 pts/0    23613 R+    1000   0:00          \_ ps jfax
```

I was particularly interested in how it acquires new `pty` before realizing the PPID issue (named `pts/1` here) so I did `strace -ff gnome-terminal` and it shows two `exec`, one for `gnome-terminal` an another for `gnome-terminal.real` and none of the PIDs is that of our newly created terminal.

I'm assuming it sends some message to terminal server over a unix socket or something but I can't quite find it and I can't strace the `gnome-terminal-server` either, even with `sudo` because `Operation not permitted`.

If I grep `socket` I can find some `unix sockets` indeed but I can't find any useful clue connecting it to `PID 22404`.

Anyone knows the steps of spawning a new terminal and how it acquires new `ptys`, or alternatively how I can investigate this socket or ...?

Comment: Like all the gnome sticky brown matter, gnome-terminal-server and gnome-terminal-client communicate over [dbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus), which itself runs over Unix domain sockets. The gnome-terminal-server itself implements all the terminal related stuff via the [vte library](https://developer.gnome.org/vte/0.26/), so it's there you should look for the lower level stuff. If you're just about "acquiring a new pty" and such simple stuff, look at the openpty(3) implementation in glibc.

Comment: I already described the architecture back in 2017 at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407863/5132 .