# How to prevent processes from being killed when I log out of GNOME?

Tags: ubuntu, process, tmux, gnome3

So far I was used to be able to run `tmux` via SSH and if I disconnected, the `tmux` session would still be running when I connected back.

So I assumed that the same could be done by starting a tmux session as one user (using GNOME's Terminal application) and then log out of GNOME and reconnect to it, e.g. via SSH. Turns out I was wrong.

Interestingly when I do the following as a workaround, it seems to work:

1. `ssh $(whoami)@localhost`
2. start `tmux` session
3. disconnect
4. log off from GNOME
5. log back in as another user
6. use SSH to connect to the user from step 1
7. reconnect to `tmux` session

Alas, I don't get why GNOME seemingly kills all the processes of said user when logging off.

Is there a better way than the above workaround? Some GNOMEish counterpart of Bash's built-ins `fg`/`bg`/`disown`, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meanwhile I have researched this further. The pointer with systemd by Nicholas was spot on. Several ways seem to exist to mitigate the issue:

### 1. `logind.conf`

[`/etc/systemd/logind.conf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html) and friends contain three relevant settings:

- `KillUserProcesses=` (if `yes` a logoff will cause processes within the scope of the [`systemd-logind.service(8)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.service.html) session to be killed.
- `KillOnlyUsers=` will allow to limit the list of users for which the above setting applies (space-separated list, e.g. `adam eve joe jane`).
- `KillExcludeUsers=` is the opposite of the previous setting an makes users exempt from the effect of `KillUserProcesses=yes`.

So one could set `KillUserProcesses=no` or only include user `gdm` in `KillOnlyUsers` (if using GNOME) or list the users to be exempt from process killing on login session teardown via `KillExcludeUsers`.

You can see sessions with `loginctl list-sessions`.

### 2. `loginctl enable-linger username`

You can enable lingering for the current session by executing [`loginctl(1)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html) as follows within the session scope (obviously replace `username` for the actual user name or `$(whoami)`):

```
loginctl enable-linger username
```

The clue can be found from the [`logind.conf(5)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html) manual page:

> In addition to session processes, user process may run under the user manager unit `user@.service`. Depending on the linger settings, this may allow users to run processes independent of their login sessions. See the description of `enable-linger` in [`loginctl(1)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html).

### 3. `systemd-run --scope --user command`

The manual for [`logind.conf(5)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html) contains the clue to this one:

> Note that setting `KillUserProcesses=yes` will break tools like `screen(1)` and `tmux(1)`, unless they are moved out of the session scope. See example in [`systemd-run(1)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html).

And indeed looking at the manual for [`systemd-run(1)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html) we find the following example:

> #### Example 5. Start screen as a user service
>
> ```
> $ systemd-run --scope --user screen Running scope as unit
> run-r14b0047ab6df45bfb45e7786cc839e76.scope.
>
> $ screen -ls There is a screen on:
>         492..laptop     (Detached) 1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-fatima.
> ```
>
> This starts the `screen` process as a child of
> the `systemd --user` process that was started by `user@.service`, in a
> scope unit. A `systemd.scope(5)` unit is used instead of a
> `systemd.service(5)` unit, because `screen` will exit when detaching from
> the terminal, and a service unit would be terminated. Running screen
> as a user unit has the advantage that it is not part of the session
> scope. If `KillUserProcesses=yes` is configured in `logind.conf(5)`, the
> default, the session scope will be terminated when the user logs out
> of that session.

---

Tested with

```
systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.2)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be this is related to systemd, at some point I heard that they were killing all daemon processes on logoff (ignoring decades of previous Unix practice!), but I haven't heard of it for a while so I thought they either changed back, that it is something that is easy to fix or that packagers were dealing with so users didn't see it.

Anyway, if it is systemd, there are other answers that you mind find and try, for example [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802189/how-to-run-tmux-screen-with-systemd-230).

Comment: Whoa ... thanks for the answer. But most of all **thanks for Tmux!** (and still taking the time to answer).

Comment: It will be related to GNOME Terminal.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407863/5132 .  The server runs as a per-user service, and per-user service management is torn down at logoff.