# Double ssh -X not working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, x11, sshd

I'm on a using ssh -X to get into a gateway server (GW) and from there to another machine (A). Things work and I'm able to open applications (like gedit).

However, when I do the same thing to open apps on Machine B (again through GW) I run into problems. 
I can open `xclock` but not `gedit` or other programs (I'm not getting any errors either).

I've tried to set the settings on the server (/etc/ssh/sshd_config) as follows:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

But things are still not working. Also, with `echo $DISPLAY` I get: `localhost:10.0`

Comment: try `ssh -Y` instead of `ssh -X` (using `-Y` instead of `-X` sets `ForwardX11Trusted` on, which is the default on debian/ubuntu but not on other systems).

Comment: tried that too, didn't work.

Comment: `gedit` and other gnome things do their own "application server" / dbus thing and may end up opening the window on the _local_ display. Maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526553/308316) could help.

Comment: This worked! If you write it as an answer, I'll star it