# Windows in X session opening on wrong display

Tags: x11, display

I want to solve a problem with Zoom's screen sharing (it conflicts with wayland and suggests using X). I can get Zoom to work, but the problem is that most but not all applications in the X session are opened on the wrong display.

Here's what I'm doing:
I open a virtual console and start an X session with `startx -- :1`.
The output of `who` is

```
user    tty2         2020-04-15 06:44 (tty2)
user    tty3         2020-04-15 07:26
user    pts/4        2020-04-15 07:27 (:1)
```

`$DISPLAY` is `:0` on `tty2`

I can now open certain applications (like xterm, Firefox, Zoom (screen sharing works!)) on `:1` (either with `DISPLAY=:1; firefox` from `:0` or directly from `:1`).

The problem is that most applications (like terminator, gedit) are opened automatically on `tty2` with no error message. How can I fix this?

For the record:
I am using GNOME on Debian 10.
I ran `DISPLAY=:1; xhost +` but that didn't change anything.

I am using the `~/.xinitrc` file from [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Xinitrc) (using `gnome-session` instead of `x-window-manager` did not make a difference)
Maybe relevant:
There is a default `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` which only calls `/etc/X11/Xsession`. `Xsession` itself doesn't seem to start a window manager. So without my `~/.xinitrc`, `startx` jumps right back to the console.

EDIT:

Choosing "GNOME on Xorg" from gdm3's login screen remedies the situation. Thanks mosvy for the suggestion.

I also tried the suggestions from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526553). Running

```
export $(dbus-launch)
gnome-terminal
```

did not change anything, but

```
#! /bin/bash
ID=foo.bar$RANDOM
GDK_BACKEND=x11 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server --app-id "$ID" &
sleep .4        # yuck
gnome-terminal --app-id "$ID"
wait
```

worked (`gnome-terminal` is opened on display `:1`), but I guess this solution cannot be applied to other apps.

Comment: Note: `xhost +` turns of security, nothing more. You should avoid its use.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, but the question lacks the clarity that it needs for me to make any suggestions. Please give some clear examples of what you did, and how it does not work. Don't describe them, show them. I typed .... and this happened.

Comment: I think it's about the same thing as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526553/308316). Try running `export $(dbus-launch)` in your xterm, then `gedit` and other gnome-stuff should work.

Comment: Notice that you can choose a "gnome on Xorg" session from gdm3's login screen.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: thanks, I edited the question. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @mosvy: thanks for the link. Unfortunately `export $(dbus-launch)` did not work; see my edit in the question.

Comment: Try running the message bus as `export DISPLAY=:1; export $(env - "LANG=$LANG" "DISPLAY=$DISPLAY" dbus-launch)` before launching `gedit` or `gnome-terminal`. If that works, try with `export DISPLAY=:1; export $(env -u XDG_RUNTIME_DIR dbus-launch)` too.

Comment: But this is just out of technical interest; as I already said, you do NOT need to run a separate Xorg server; you can simply choose "GNOME on Xorg" from the menu opened by the gear icon in gdm3's login screen. Gdm3 will remember your choice. (and other display managers have similar options).

Comment: @mosvy: Logged in with GNOME on Xorg and everything works. Thank you so much.

Comment: Related: [Gnome applications over ssh open on the remote X session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638459/gnome-applications-over-ssh-open-on-the-remote-x-session)