# Gnome applications over ssh open on the remote X session

Tags: ssh, x11, gnome, display

I am ssh-ing (with ForwardX11 on) from an Ubuntu laptop to a remote OpenSUSE desktop.  Both are running X11.

Some applications like xterm, xclock etc. open on the calling computer's display (Ubuntu), which is the behaviour I want.  But others, like eog, nautilus, etc. open on the OpenSUSE desktop's X11 display - even though the `DISPLAY` variable is set to the local (Ubuntu) X11 display.  How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Related: [Windows in X session opening on wrong display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580177/windows-in-x-session-opening-on-wrong-display)

Comment: At least in the case of nautilus, it's likely because it connects to an already-running instance of the application. See for example [ssh -X to open a file manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109531/ssh-x-to-open-a-file-manager) .

Answer (score 3):

Just found the solution.
Unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR then it works.

Comment: Thanks, this is also relevant for using several tty with different X sessions on the same machine. My problem was that calling say gnome-terminal in a tty, just opened a new terminal in my older Xsession (living in another tty).